# How to edit the properties of a page programmatically?

Tags: plugin-development, pages

I know that I can programmatically create a new page via wp_insert_post setting 'post-type' to 'page.'

How do I go about editing that page programmatically? (title, content, slug, etc.)

Also, if I wanted to set the template for that page programmatically, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, you can insert title, content, slug, etc. using `wp_insert_post` then use `update_post_meta` to assign the template to that post.

You can write like this

```
$post_arr = array(
    'post_title'=>'My title goes here',
    'post_content'=>'This is my long content.',
    'post_excerpt' => 'My Excerpt',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post_arr);
```

Then set template like this.

```
update_post_meta( $new_post_id, '_wp_page_template',  'template-file.php' );
```

To see more options for `wp_insert_post`, you can check it's documentation page.

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: @Eli if you look up the docs there's a `wp_update_post`, which is just a wrapper around `wp_insert_post`, but keep in mind we have a 1 question per question policy here, don't "mung" or "squish" all your questions together, it can drastically reduce the opportunities for answers

Comment: To edit/update the data, you can pass `ID` to the `$post_arr`, if a post with that ID exists, `wp_insert_post` will update old data instead of creating a new one.